# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Rational.CGauss.fcrReal'

Tags: c#, static

Ive been working on this and cant seem to figure it out why I'm getting the error in the title of the page. It looks like the error is coming out of my operator part at the end of the code.  I have tried to put the fcrReal and fcrImg in their own pubic static part of the code which didn't work either.  Any help would be awesome

Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Rational
{
    class CGauss   
    {
       private CRational fcrReal;
       private CRational fcrImg;
       private bool fbValid;


    public CGauss()
       {         
           fbValid = true;               
       }

    public CGauss(string strCGauss)
    {
        Parse(strCGauss);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string strGauss;
        if (!fbValid)
            strGauss = "NaN";
        else
        {
             strGauss = fcrReal.ToString() + fcrImg.ToString() + "i";            
        }
        return strGauss;
    }
    public void Parse(string CGauss)
    { 

    }  
     public static CGauss operator + (CGauss gNum1, CGauss gNum2)
         {
             CGauss gSum = new CGauss();

                 fcrReal = gNum1.fcrReal + gNum2.fcrReal;
                 fcrImg = gNum1.fcrImg + gNum2.fcrImg;
                 gSum.fbValid = true;     

                 return gSum;
         }
        public static  CGauss operator - (CGauss gNum1, CGauss gNum2)
         {
             CGauss gSum = new CGauss();

             fcrReal = gNum1.fcrReal - gNum2.fcrReal;
             fcrImg = gNum1.fcrImg - gNum2.fcrImg; 
             return gSum;
         }
         public static CGauss operator*(CGauss gNum1, CGauss gNum2)
        {
            CGauss gSum = new CGauss();

            fcrReal = (gNum1.fcrReal * gNum2.fcrReal) - (gNum1.fcrImg * gNum2.fcrImg);
            fcrImg = (gNum1.fcrReal * gNum2.fcrImg) + (gNum1.fcrReal + gNum2.fcrReal); 

              return gSum;
        }
         public static CGauss operator / (CGauss gNum1, CGauss gNum2)
         {
             CGauss gSum = new CGauss();

             fcrReal = (gNum1.fcrReal * gNum2.fcrReal) + (gNum1.fcrImg * gNum2.fcrImg) / (gNum2.fcrReal * gNum2.fcrReal) + (gNum2.fcrImg * gNum2.fcrImg);
             fcrImg = (gNum1.fcrImg * gNum2.fcrReal) - (gNum1.fcrReal * gNum2.fcrImg) / (gNum2.fcrReal * gNum2.fcrReal) + (gNum2.fcrImg * gNum2.fcrImg);
          return gSum;
         }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the operators are static and take in the objects to be worked on.  You need to prefix the `fcrReal =` and `fcrImg =` with `gSum.` as below:

```
public static CGauss operator*(CGauss gNum1, CGauss gNum2)
    {
        CGauss gSum = new CGauss();

        gSum.fcrReal = (gNum1.fcrReal * gNum2.fcrReal) - (gNum1.fcrImg * gNum2.fcrImg);
        gSum.fcrImg = (gNum1.fcrReal * gNum2.fcrImg) + (gNum1.fcrReal + gNum2.fcrReal); 

          return gSum;
    }
```